# Unable to start embedded Jetty server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, jar

I have made a spring boot project.

When I make a jar using windows 10 and run on my windows machine it works without a problem.

When I try running it on either Debian 10 or CentOS 8 with Java 8 installed I get

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-02-02 20:22:13.050 ERROR 14537 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Jetty server
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyWebServer.start(JettyWebServer.java:165) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:297) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552) ~[spring-context-5.1.10.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) [spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.9.RELEASE]
        at ptoject.web.Application.main(Application.java:14) [classes!/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [web-4.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [web-4.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) [web-4.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) [web-4.jar:na]
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:342) ~[jetty-server-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:308) ~[jetty-server-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80) ~[jetty-server-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236) ~[jetty-server-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-util-9.4.19.v20190610.jar!/:9.4.19.v20190610]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyWebServer.start(JettyWebServer.java:146) ~[spring-boot-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.9.RELEASE]
```

If it is any help this is my build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.9.RELEASE")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.9.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

group = 'project'
version = '4'
mainClassName = "project.web.Application"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    }
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.tomcat', module: 'tomcat-jdbc'
    }
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail';
    implementation 'com.h2database:h2'
    implementation 'org.webjars:jquery:3.1.0'
    implementation 'commons-validator:commons-validator:1.6'
}

jar {
    // include all the jars
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
        (configurations.runtime).collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'web.Application'
    }
}
```

I am at a complete loss as to why this is happening

Debian 10 and CentOS 8 has

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_232-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)
```

And windows machine has

```
java version "1.8.0_241"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_241-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.241-b07, mixed mode)
```

Comment: `java.net.SocketException: Permission denied` means you're not allowed to bind the port. I'm guessing you're trying something like port 80 or 443 which needs elevated permissions

Comment: all ports below 1024 are only allowed to be run as root. And you should not run java applications as root, that is a security risk. You can read more about it here https://serverfault.com/questions/112795/how-to-run-a-server-on-port-80-as-a-normal-user-on-linux

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I am willing to take the security risk. How would I run java as root on port 80? Or if I can't run on port 80 then how can I point port 80 to my spring boot application running on port >1024?

Comment: read the link i posted.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I can accept your answer as correct one if you answer it. Also your link doesn't explain why it is a security risk. Additionally it works if I run the java process as root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All ports below 1024 are only allowed to be opened by root. Thats why spring boot applications usually are run at port 8080 and instead you have some sort of proxy/loadbalancer redirecting the traffic from 80 to 8080.

Why you don't want to run an application as root, is because if you have a vulnerability/bug in your application that allows for "remote code execution" (someone can execute malicious code through your application) then that piece of code will be run as root, which is the most powerful user on the linux server.

Then the attacker can basically do whatever they want on the server/machine.

There are several recommendations in this thread how to solve your problem https://serverfault.com/questions/112795/how-to-run-a-server-on-port-80-as-a-normal-user-on-linux

But i will never recommend anyone to run an application as root, it is a major security risk. I rather run it on a different port (like 8080).

Comment: Probably also not advised, but the quick way to get past this in .NET for me was to run the IDE as an administrator.

Comment: running the ide as an admin, puts you at risk for what is written above. The application is then run as an administrator witch is as dangerous.